# How to display "fixed postion" overlay in mapview?

Tags: android

I simply would like to display icon that is in fixed location in MapView. Overlay will do if it's fixed, but the problem with overlay that it's move as user moves the map. But I need to have this icon fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose your MapView and an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="X" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```